# count records from sql table and display it on textbox

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I knew this is simple but I am not able to think. Displaying the count of a record from table and display it on textbox.

```
private void gMapControl1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conDatabase = new SqlConnection(constring);
    conDatabase.Open();
    DataTable db = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(
        "select count(site) from [ICPS].[dbo].[excel GPS postcode]",
        conDatabase);

    sda.Fill(db);
    textBox29.Text = ;

    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(
        "select count(site) from [ICPS].[dbo].[excel GPS postcode] "
            + "where Region = '1'",
        conDatabase);

    sda.Fill(db);
    textBox30.Text = ;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to use `SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar` instead of `SqlDataAdapter` like this:

```
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select count(site) from [ICPS].[dbo].[excel GPS postcode]", conDatabase);
object count = com.ExecuteScalar();
if(count != null) textBox29.Text = count.ToString();
//The same for textBox30
```

More info on [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx)
Note that the code I posted is just for the idea of using `ExecuteScalar`, it depends on your `code style` when working with `ADO.NET`, you may want to use some `using` statement, or `reuse` your `command, ...` in your own way you like.

Answer (score 3):

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
   conn.Open();
   cmd.CommandText = "select count(site) from [ICPS].[dbo].[excel GPS postcode]";
   Int32 count = (Int32) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
   textBox29.Text = count.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you expect just one value returned by your sql command, then use [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) from the command object

```
string cmdText1 = "select count(site) from [ICPS].[dbo].[excel GPS postcode]";
using(SqlConnection conDatabase = new SqlConnection(constring))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conDatabase))
{
      conDatabase.Open();
      int numRec = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
      textBox29.Text = numRec.ToString();
}
```

MSDN says

> Executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in
>   the result set returned by the query. Additional columns or rows are
>   ignored

However I have noticed that you try to read the record count from two different queries.
So your code could also be written in this way to avoid a roundtrip to the database

```
string cmdText = "select count(site) from [ICPS].[dbo].[excel GPS postcode];" + 
                 "select count(site) from [ICPS].[dbo].[excel GPS postcode] " +
                 "where Region = '1'", ;
using(SqlConnection conDatabase = new SqlConnection(constring))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conDatabase))
{
      conDatabase.Open();
      using(SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
      {
          reader.Read();
          int numRec1 = Convert.ToInt32(reader[0]);
          reader.NextResult();
          reader.Read();
          int numRec2 = Convert.ToInt32(reader[0]);
          textBox29.Text = numRec1.ToString();
          textBox30.Text = numRec2.ToString();
      }
}
```

In this way I have taken advantage of the ability of SQL Server to execute two or more commands separated by a semicolon.

Comment: Thanks everyone.. Sorry for the late response .. with your help issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

To fetch a value from datatable use  `row[columnName]`

```
 SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(
    "select count(site) As siteCount  from [ICPS].[dbo].[excel GPS postcode]",
    conDatabase);


sda.Fill(db);
if(db !=null && db.Rows.Count > 0)
textBox29.Text =db["siteCount"].tostring();
else
textBox29.Text ="0";
```

However as ***King King*** suggested here why use datatable if you have to fetch just a single row and single column use `ExecuteScalar` method .

Executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query. Additional columns or rows are ignored. -[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx)

```
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select count(site) from [ICPS].[dbo].[excel GPS postcode]", conDatabase);
object siteCount = com.ExecuteScalar();
if(siteCount != null) textBox29.Text = siteCount.ToString();
```